# taskqueues: zombie tasks

Tags: google-app-engine

I have 7 tasks in my default queue that will not go away.

I've used this solution to solve this in a non-default queue:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/msg/4f3c7818285be873

I don't even see any HTTP 500s in my access log, it's as if the tasks are being "executed", but not really submitting any HTTP requests.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

When viewing your logs, you need to select 'Requests only' in order to see all requests. It's quite likely that your tasks are being (re)executed, but you're not seeing them in the logs because they're returning a non-200 status code but not throwing an exception which would show up on the default 'exceptions' view of the logs.

Comment: you're right, after tweaking my log view I saw that my tasks were returning 404s (I had been searching for 500s).  thanks Nick!